# Extra Older Packages with latest non profit starter pack 3.0

Tags: npsp

So i recently updated a client to the latest non-profit starter pack and things are working great so far.

Whats confusing me is I'm not sure if i can "uninstall" all the separete packages and just leave the one new non-profit starter pack? or do they need to stay?

[image]

I see "Recurring donations", "Relationships" "Affliations" "Contacts and Organizations" and "Households"

I assume i can remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Power of Us Hub](http://www.salesforcefoundation.org/help/power-of-us-hub/) maintains the documentation for the NPSP. Useful links you might want to have are the [NPSP 3.0 Documentation](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-3-Documentation), the [NPSP Workbook](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-Workbook) and the [link to install/upgrade to NPSP 3](https://mrbelvedere.salesforcefoundation.org/mpinstaller/npsp). I hope you read the [Release Notes](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/wiki/Release-Notes) before doing an update to 3.0 as there's preparation that needed to be done in some orgs in advance before doing the update.

The latest Non-Profit Starter Pack (NPSP) has 5 interrelated packages to it that sit on top of an EE org: Contacts and Organizations, Affiliations, Relationships, Recurring Donations and Households. While I've uninstalled them individually in an org as part of uninstalling the entire package, the latest info from @ JasonLantz is that my individual package uninstall should have failed, so it's not advised. Since space isn't an issue, there'd be no gain in removing just one part of the package.

You might want to consider installing [Nonprofits 101](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B39t7EAB) from Cloud for Good. Its a free Salesforce Help/Knowledge-base for Nonprofit and Educational Organizations meant to be used with the NPSP as a resource for training and reference to help users with the many SF features unique to the NPSP.

Comment: I wanted to correct one point in this answer:  with NPSP 3.0, you cannot uninstall any of the 5 original NPSP packages (Contacts & Organizations, Households, Recurring Donations, Relationships, and Affiliations) as the new Nonprofit Starter Pack package is an extension of all 5 original packages.  Thus, with NPSP 3.0 you cannot individually uninstall any of the original packages even if you're not using them.  However, the new versions of the original packages are pretty stripped down in 3.0 as all the logic was moved into the new extension package.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jason. I've uninstalled them in an org once and remember that I had to do it where relationships was the last one I uninstalled of the five.

Comment: For the original 5 packages, Households is the only one that has a dependency on another package (Contacts & Organizations).  All the other packages are not extensions and can be installed/uninstalled independently with pre-3.0 versions.  It's possible you had issues with unpackaged page layouts or profiles that required a different uninstall order.  With 3.0, attempting to uninstall any of the 5 original packages would fail due to dependencies from the Nonprofit Starter Pack extension package.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't recall if this org had the old NPSP in it first with no data followed by 3.0 or not which could possibly explain what you describe. I do appreciate you jumping in with the correct info and will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot remove the individual packages since they are still used as the core components in NPSP 3.0.  The NPSP 3.0 upgrade actually upgrades each individual package to the 3.x version.  Here is a screenshot of an org with NPSP 2; notice the older version number of the individual packages.

[image]